# Is it possible to have more than one active windows on Lion?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I am in a situation where I really need to have multiple windows to be active simultaneously. I know it is against the optimization principle of most operating systems, but is it possible?

Here is my story: I will be presenting a network project this weekend at somewhere far from my university. We have a working demo that shows a synchronized car racing game. Ideally, to present our demo I need at least two Macs: I can make our demo run on all machines and show the effect of synchronization. However, I have only one Mac - my laptop. So I came up with a solution: to run multiple instances of our demo software on my laptop. I tested it and it worked fine. Although it's networking on the same machine, it is still networking. But the problem is: Lion would only give me one active window at a time. I can switch between windows of couse, but only the currently active window would update, other windows just remain static. To show a synchronized game, I need multiple windows to be active - I want the multiple demo windows to update simultaneously, as if they were on different machines.

To re-state my question: I want to place, say four windows on my screen and I want all of them to be active windows. Is that possible at all on Lion?

Comment: If the windows don't update while not beeing "active" this is probabably more of a programming issues than an OS X issue per se. Can't you change your demo app to always update the screen?

Comment: @patrix Oh... I didn't know that.. Thanks! I'll look on line to see if I could change the code.

Comment: @patrix Okay I changed my code and it worked out fine!!

Comment: Programming questions are better suited for Stack Overflow actually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it doesn't work with all of the applications, you could use the flag **-n** for the *Terminal's* **open** command.

> **-n**  Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running.

Comment: It opens a new instance, but still, I have only one active window at a time...

Comment: @CherryQu I'm with patrix, as far as I understand the situation, the windows should update by themselves, unless it requires some sort of input, which is a complete different issue.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I'll try to change my code then! I don't think it requires any other input. In an inactive window, the main player will remain there, but other players shall move -- that's what I want to see!

Comment: Okay I changed the code and it works fine!!! Thanks!